# convert CURLcode res to a char*

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I want to receive the contents of a webpage to work with.
So i need the contents to be stored in a variable `char*`/`string`

Since you can display the contents with `printf` i was trying to use `sprintf` to see if i can store the contents but it's not working at all

```c
int main () {
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    char rstr[80];

    if(curl) {
        CURLcode res;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/png");
        res  = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        printf("%u\n",res);
        sprintf(rstr,"%u\n",res);
    }

    printf("%s\n",rstr);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```html
<html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html>0
0
```

While expecting:

```html
<html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html>0
<html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html>0
```

This means the `printf("%u\n",res);` shows the contents and an additional 0.
but `sprintf(rstr,"%u\n",res);` just contains 0 without the site contents.

How can i convert/store the contents  to a `char[]`, `char*` or `string`?

Comment: Are you sure that `curl` is a non-null pointer? What happens of `curl_easy_init` fails and you print the *uninitialized* contents of `rstr`?

Comment: if it fails it will, but then it won't print <html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html>0 in the line above since the printf("%u\n",res); will only be execute when it pass

Comment: Now please explain *why* you expected the body to be printed twice? `CURLcode` is a single integer value, there's nothing inside your code that receives and prints the body. The output of the response you get is the default behavior when neither [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) nor [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) options are set. It's *not* from your printing of `res`.

Comment: If you want the contents of the web site into a memory buffer, use the [getinmemory](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) example.